# Error: incorrect signature: void get(Id) from the type String and Missing retrn statement reqired return type

Tags: apex, compile-error

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ResponseWrapper dupNameCheck(Persons__c record, string srId, string pageId) {
    list < string > id = new list < string > ();
    list < Persons__c > dupPersons = new list < Persons__c > ();
    map < string, Persons__c > uniqueNameMap = new map < string, Persons__c > ();
    list < string > linkedSR = new list < string > ();
    for (Persons__c personObj: record) {
        if (personObj.Record_Type_API_Name__c != 'test_signture') {
            if (String.isNotBlank(personObj.Id)) {
                id.add(personObj.Id);
            }
            if (personObj.Service_Request__c != null) {
                linkedSR.add(personObj.Service_Request__c);
            }
            if (personObj.First_Name__c != null) {
                if (pageId == null || (pageId != null && personObj.First_Name__c != pageId.get(personObj.id).First_Name__c)) {
                    if (uniqueNameMap.containsKey(personObj.First_Name__c) &&
                        uniqueNameMap.get(personObj.First_Name__c).Service_Request__c == personObj.Service_Request__c) {
                        dupPersons.add(personObj);
                    } else {
                        uniqueNameMap.put(personObj.First_Name__c, personObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!uniqueNameMap.isEmpty()) {
        for (Persons__c personObj: [select id, First_Name__c, Entity__c, Service_Request__c from Persons__c
                where Id NOT IN: id
                AND Service_Request__c IN: linkedSR
                AND First_Name__c IN: uniqueNameMap.KeySet()
            ]) {
            if (uniqueNameMap.containsKey(personObj.First_Name__c) &&
                uniqueNameMap.get(personObj.First_Name__c).Service_Request__c == personObj.Service_Request__c) {
                dupPersons.add(uniqueNameMap.get(personObj.First_Name__c));
            }
        }
    }

    for (Persons__c pObj: dupPersons) {
        if (pObj.Record_Type_API_Name__c != 'test_signture' && pObj.Original_Person__c == null)
            pObj.addError('Similar first name matched');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put your code through a code formatter: getting the indenting corrected makes it easier to reason about the code.

The `get` problem is this expression `pageId.get(personObj.id)` because `pageId` is a `String` not a `Map` that has a `get` method.

The code is not returning anything so you need to add code that creates and returns an instance of `ResponseWrapper`.

This code would be easier to maintain if you applied the [Extract Method](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method) approach to separate out the main parts of the logic.